# Trouble getting DARKSTAT to work in my laptop and keep getting Unable to connect... problem setting up the config file

Tags: networking

I've just installed Darkstat in my ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS and I don't seem to get the configuration right.

### I've run ifconfig and gotten:

```
enp2s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 34:97:f6:72:5d:ce  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 206402  bytes 16392704 (16.3 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 206402  bytes 16392704 (16.3 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp3s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.7  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::6af0:14a1:e5d5:642f  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 2800:40:19:281:4eac:a63a:cdb7:1866  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 2800:40:19:281:a6aa:1d8c:a054:b835  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether a4:02:b9:24:cf:5c  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 711506  bytes 776107164 (776.1 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 4  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 337444  bytes 158220575 (158.2 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

### With that information I'm configuring Darkstat:

```
# Turn this to yes when you have configured the options below.
START_DARKSTAT=yes

# Don't forget to read the man page.

# You must set this option, else darkstat may not listen to
# the interface you want
INTERFACE="-i wlp3s0"

DIR="/var/lib/darkstat"
PORT="-p 666"
BINDIP="-b 127.0.0.1"
LOCAL="-l 192.168.1.7/255.255.255.0"

# File will be relative to $DIR:
# DAYLOG="--daylog darkstat.log"

# Don't reverse resolve IPs to host names
#DNS="--no-dns"

#FILTER="not (src net 192.168.0 and dst net 192.168.0)"

# Additional command line Arguments:
# OPTIONS="--syslog --no-macs"
```

**Please note that I've tried `192.168.1.1` (my router), and `192.168.1.0`**

### After saving the file I've run:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/darkstat restart
```

I'm trying to get in the browser into `localhost/666` and `127.0.0.1/666` and I get "*Unable to connect*" message.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Port numbers need to be separated from the host name by a colon, not a slash.
So you should point your browser to `localhost:666` or `127.0.0.1:666`.

Comment: Thanks! What a silly mistake! 
Anyway, I still get the error.
I've tried doing `darkstat -i wlp3s0` and I get an error:
`40525: warning: bind("0.0.0.0") failed: Address already in use`
`40525: warning: bind("::") failed: Address already in use`
`40525: error: was not able to bind any ports for http interface`
Again, thanks for your help!!!

Comment: Doing `sudo lsof -i:666` I get nothing

Comment: Following [this link](https://greenitsolutions.at/darkstat-debian-linux-traffic-analyzer/), I've changed the port to 8000 and the problem remains the same.

Comment: When doing `service darkstat status`
I get:
`● darkstat.service - LSB: start darkstat monitoring system at boot time
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/darkstat; generated)
     Active: active (exited) since Tue 2022-04-12 19:33:30 -03; 1min 23s ago
       Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
    Process: 42296 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/darkstat start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)`

Comment: And this
`Apr 12 19:33:30 Rosamunda systemd[1]: Starting LSB: start darkstat monitoring system at boot time...
Apr 12 19:33:30 Rosamunda darkstat[42296]:  * Starting darkstat network daemon : darkstat
Apr 12 19:33:30 Rosamunda darkstat[42296]:    ...done.
Apr 12 19:33:30 Rosamunda systemd[1]: Started LSB: start darkstat monitoring system at boot time.`

Comment: Two observations: First, it seems your `darkstat` installation isn't using the configuration file you posted, since your first error message says it tries to bind to `0.0.0.0` even though your config says `BINDIP="-b 127.0.0.1"`. And second, if `darkstat` complains "Address already in use" even though `lsof` there's nothing on the port then that's a bug which you should take up with the author of the program.